# Magento down, Exception Error SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: magento-1.9

This has happened before and it seemed to be the maintenance.flag file staying so I would have to rename it "maintenance.flag_", I fixed this by not allowing it to put the site into maintenance mode while doing backups.

New issue popped up this morning with the Error code "933412900636" and the contents listed below;

```
a:4:{i:0;s:98:"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pctekcom_magento'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2994:"
#0 /home/pctekcom/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/pctekcom/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/pctekcom/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/pctekcom/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/pctekcom/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/pctekcom/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

There is now a new error popping up after deleting the maintenance.flag files.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/pctekcom/public_html/errors/report.php' (include_path='/home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/pctekcom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/pctekcom/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/pctekcom/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 925

There is no file called report.php in the directory /errors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong username and password or invalid access rights to you MySQL server.

Check `app/etc/local.xml` and verify your credentials.

If you need to reset you MySQL password you have to access your MySQL shell and use the following command (replace with correct information):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdbname.* TO 'pctekcom_magento'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
```

**NOTE**: MySQL username and password, **NOT** Magento username and password.

If you have phpMyAdmin you can use the "users" function.

Also try using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` in your `app/etc/local.xml`, sometimes it fails the reverse lookup for localhost.

Comment: I don't have access to Shell as I'm on shared hosting. I updated all privileges, using cpanel and it's set to ALL PRIVILEGES. I changed the password in local.xml and double-verified that.

Comment: Try manually flushing your cache by removing the content of var/cache folder (do not delete the folder itself)

Comment: Try modifying your local.xml using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"

Comment: There are alot of files, safe to delete them all?
I tried with localhost, same thing. :-/

Comment: Deleting var/cache content is 100% safe. Just make sure you do not delete the folder itself.

Comment: Deleting now will report back in a moment

Comment: Same issue, I'll update error above if it's changed, let me check.
I'm going to create a new user and see if that helps

Comment: Creating a new user must solve or you have some serious problem on your MySQL server

Comment: I've updated my post, new error now with mage.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36101/discussion-between-riccardot-and-suranyi).

Comment: After chat: at the end the "localhost" maneuver solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Helped by " RiccardoT".

MySQL seemed to spit the dummy and pointing to "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" on a NEW USER with ALL PRIVILEGES.

Comment: He helped me through chat, will accept now.